# Selecting a series from dual in Oracle using connect by: column alias not recognized in prior clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I am trying to select a sequence from dual. The following is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

Executing the following query is successful:

```
select
  1 as curr_val,
  2 as next_val
from
  dual
connect by
  level <=3 
;
```

However, when I try to create the sequence by doing the following I get the error shown below.

```
select
  1 as curr_val,
  2 as next_val
from
  dual
connect by
  level <=3 
  and curr_val = prior next_val
;
```

Error:

```
ORA-00904: "NEXT_VAL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 24
```

Is there a way to modify the above to generate a sequence of numbers (i.e. get the above query to return 1,2,3 for the values of curr_val)?

Comment: You can't use an alias from the select clause in the where clause.  You either use the unaliased name or create a nested query with the aliases and select from that.  It's not clear what curr_val and next_val are supposed to represent in your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
select rownum curr_val, rownum + 1 next_val
from dual
connect by level <=10
order by 1;
```

The ORDER BY clause might not be required if the ordering is not important (unlikely but it's your call) or if the RDBMS' implied ordering is always going to be guaranteed (also unlikely).

Addendum: John is correct regarding the redundancy of what previously was in the text of the SQL statement above.

Comment: Please note that the "level <=10" and "fetch first 10 rows only" are redundant (i.e. results would be the same if either one or the other was removed from the query... the query would be better (more concise, clearer) with just one of these clauses).